# Intercambiar items de una lista a otra

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo un ejemplo de estas listas:

```html
<h2> Lista 1 </h2>
<ul class="lista1" id="lista1">
      <li>Item1</li>
      <li>Item2</li>
      <li>Item3</li>
      <li>Item4</li>
 </ul>
            
<h2> Lista 2 </h2>
    <ul class="lista2" id="lista2">
      <li>Item5</li>
      <li>Item6</li>
       <li>Item7</li>
    </ul>
```

Lo que deseo es solo invertir las listas dándole `click` a un botón: Los items de la lista 1 se pasen a la lista 2 y que los items de la lista 2 se pasen a la lista 1.

Comment: Se acepta jquery?

Comment: Claro que si...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solo obten en innerHTML de ambos elementos y asignandoselo al otro lo logras.

```js
 

function invertir()
{
    var contenido1 = document.getElementById("lista1").innerHTML;
    var contenido2 = document.getElementById("lista2").innerHTML;
 
    document.getElementById("lista1").innerHTML = contenido2;
    document.getElementById("lista2").innerHTML = contenido1;   
}
```

```html
<h2> Lista 1 </h2>
<ul class="lista1" id="lista1">
   <li>Item1</li>
   <li>Item2</li>
   <li>Item3</li>
   <li>Item4</li>
</ul>
            
<h2> Lista 2 </h2>
<ul class="lista2" id="lista2">
 <li>Item5</li>
 <li>Item6</li>
 <li>Item7</li>
</ul>

<button onclick="invertir()">Invertir</button>
```

Y con jquery utilizando el metodo `html()` que hace lo mismo que `innerHTML`:

```js
function invertir()
{
  var contenido1 = $("#lista1").html();
  var contenido2 = $("#lista2").html();
  
  $("#lista1").html(contenido2);
  $("#lista2").html(contenido1);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2> Lista 1 </h2>
    <ul class="lista1" id="lista1">
       <li>Item1</li>
       <li>Item2</li>
       <li>Item3</li>
       <li>Item4</li>
    </ul>
                
    <h2> Lista 2 </h2>
    <ul class="lista2" id="lista2">
     <li>Item5</li>
     <li>Item6</li>
     <li>Item7</li>
    </ul>

    <button onclick="invertir()">Invertir</button>
```

Comment: Hola, me funciono, gracias!

Comment: Dale una mirada a la respuesta actualiza para que la veas con jquery. Recuerda marcarla si es la solucion que esperabas.